What does list[Never] means in Python?
from typing import Never

def some_func() -> list[int] | list[Never]:
   ...

What does list[Never] means?

Have you read the docs? typing.Never

The docs say what Never is used for... but neither of the purposes described make any sense with a return type of list[Never]. If it's not just a mistake, I'm curious as well as to its purpose.

Code you found at random places on the Internet doesn't have to make sense. Do you have any reason to believe this is something that's supposed to have a valid meaning, and not just evidence of someone making a mistake?

(Note that Stack Overflow questions are supposed to be about practical, answerable problems "you actually face"; clarifying how/why this is something you "actually face" might help to make the question make more sense -- is there a particular OSS codebase or API it was seen in? If so, we could look at whether that API is making some particular atypical use of Never).

Yeah, where did you find this?

That looks like a Pylance inlay hint, which could be the inferred type for some function like def foo(b: bool): if b: return [42] return list(()).

list[Never] is a type annotation that represents an empty list type that can never contain any elements.
The Never type is a bottom type, meaning it is a subtype of all other types, but no other type is a subtype of Never. It is a special type from the typing module that is used to indicate an impossibility or a situation that can never occur. It is often used in type annotations to express that a particular code path or function is unreachable or will never execute.

Isn't list[int] | list[Never] for practical reasons the same as list[int], then? After all, an empty list complies with list[int]; there's no need for an extra branch in the type signature to express that a list is allowed to be empty.

"represents an empty list type" - I thought about that too, but is an empty list actually a type? I mean, an empty list of integers is perfectly valid, e.g. lst: list[int] = []. Maybe whoever wrote this code wasn't aware of that. Or, possibly, they're not using type hinting and instead they're using the annotation list[int] to mean a list of one or more ints.
